# mciSendString: file that contains spaces

Tags: c#, winapi, mp3, winmm, mcisendstring

If i use mciSendString (winmm.dll) and try to read file that contains spaces (for example F:\MUSIC\(01) [VA]01.StimAxel - Restart(DJ X-VenomRemix).mp3) i got an error with code 263.

mciSendString can't work with files that contains spaces. How to avoid this problem?


`Pcommand = "status \"" + path + "\" length";`


`int ret = (int)mciSendString(Pcommand, sBuffer, sBuffer.Capacity, 0);`

Comment: The string you are sending is just nonsense, *status* is for a device, not a media file.  This doesn't get better until you explain what you are *really* trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the filename with double quotes.

**Update:** According to the docs, the [`status` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798683%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) takes a device name, not a filename. You need to use [`open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743638%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to open the file on a specific device, then pass that device name to `status`.

Comment: I open it before using status. It doesnt helps. Thats because file name have spaces.